# how to remove an operating system, out of many?

Tags: fedora, windows, dual-boot

I have two o.s installed , Fedora 21 and windows 7 (ultimate), and there is GRUB bootloader, at the startup it shows four options to boot from

1. Fedora21
2. Fedora20
3. Fedora recovery mode
4. windows7

I need to remove windows7 and install some other version of it

Comment: format the fat32 partition the windows 7 is installed in. include the output of `sudo parted -l` in your question.

Answer (score 1):

## Prepare work:

1. prepare a startup USB HDD disk, you can burn an Fedora.iso into it by unetbootin. That will help you boot and reinstall the grub after installation of windows os which will overwritten the bootloader.
2. prepare a windows installation dvd.

## Action:

1 format the windows partition and install new windows os
2 use fedora USB HDD disk, to reboot your machine, and enter livedvd mode. Then you can use the terminal to mount your installed Fedora /boot partition, and reinstall grub to harddisk by following command:
`grub2-mkconfig -o ${mount-point}/grub.conf`
`grub2-install --boot-directory=${mount-point} /dev/${disk-device}`
3 reboot.

## Remark:

grub menu item `fedora 20` ? Do you install fedora 20 in another partition? if so, it will be there after you running 'grub2-mkconfig', but you can remove it by editing /boot/grub2/grub.cfg os entries, 'fedora recovery mode' an be removed by the same manner.